# Building and running Talend ESB osgi bundle

Tags: talend, esb, osgi-bundle

i am new to talend ESB so lately I started learning and i developed a job that returns a document using REST api and everything works fine, my question here is that i exported the job as a osgi bundle jar and i want to run it outside talend.Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Build the job as a Standalone Job, a ZIP file will be produced with all the required jars and script files to launch it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , when i build a job that has a REST component it only give me the osgi bundle option which generate a jar file , how can i built it as a standalone job ?

Answer (score 0):

You need an OSGI container but you can build a standalone package.

In the `Deployment` Tab, select MicroService For ESB
[image]

Then `Build Job` with a build type "Microservice" and check "Export as
ZIP"
[image]

The ZIP will contain script files ( .bat, .ps1 or .sh)  to start your Talend program from the command line.